# Creating an email template using java

Tags: java, arrays

public class EmailCreator {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Email Creator");
    System.out.println("==================================");
    String[] csv = {" james ,butler,jbutler@gmail.com",
                    "Josephine,Darakjy,Josephine_Darakjy@darakjy.org",
                    "ART,VENERE,ART@VENERE.ORG"};

    String Template = 
            "To:    (Email Adress)\n"+
            "From:  noreply@deals.com\n"+
            "Subject: Deals!\n\n"+
            "Hi (first),\n\n"+
            "We've got some great deals for you. Check our website!";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(csv));
}}
```

Hello, this is my first time posting on stack overflow, so apologies if it comes with any confusion. Please let me know if any further information is needed. I am attempting to create an email creator using java. The hope for this application is that it pulls the objects from the array and populates the designated field in the template, after that one of these template is then printed for each of these three customers (James, Josephine, and Art). I am struggling selecting an individual object from the array to fill the template, and my output is simply the array printed, not the template. Would anyone be able to help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: You need a loop around your processing part. Something like `for (String email : csv) { ... }`. You'll also need to parse said `String email` to get the name and e-mail address from one entry.

Comment: Is this for a demonstration/class assignment or for real-world use?

Comment: this is for an assignment

Comment: did you finish your assignment? or you still need to help ...

Comment: Does the template have to look like this or can you transform it into a method?